# pass multiple byte[] in a single parameter in webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

how do you pass a multiple serializable byte[]?

I assume i can't pass it as a strongly-typed array like this `List<byte[]>` to a webservice. So how do you do this?

I need to pass multiple objects of byte[] to a single webmethod, what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issue passing a serializable collection of byte arrays to a web service although the message transmission will be less than ideal. ASP.NET web services will require base64 encoding which will bloat the size of the data by about 1/3.

Optionally, instead of passing a collection of byte[], you can simply pass a jagged array such as byte[][].